# Collision on concurrent read on buffered channel in golang?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have a buffered channel that are read by multiple (4 in this example) go routines.

```
queue := make(chan string, 10000) // a large buffered channel
```

Each go routine checks the number of elements available in the channel and process them all.

```
for i :=0; i< 4; i++{ // spun 4 go routines
    go func() {
        for {
            for elem := range queue {
                // do something with the elem from the channel
            }
         }
     }
  }
```

Will multiple go routines collide on the reads? In other words, could different go routine grab the same elem in the channel, or while one go routine is reading the buffer, the other go routines already read and processed some of the elements? How to block other go routines from reading while one go routine is reading?

Comment: Trying this under the race detector would tell you more. Note that the whole idea of channels is to provide synchronization between different goroutines, so what would you expect? What would you expect after reading the language spec?

Comment: The spec states clearly that it blocks for unbuffered reads, but not clear on read for buffered channels. It would be nice to not having to use mutex explicitly for consistent reads.

Comment: The spec is clear in the buffered case too: Reads succeed if values are available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer: no.  Elements placed on a Go channel can only be read once, regardless of how many goroutines are trying to read off the channel at the same time, and that applies regardless of whether the channel is buffered or not.  There's no possibility that an element will be read by two different goroutines unless that element was *sent* to the channel more than once.  The only thing that buffering does, with regards to channel semantics, is remove the necessity for the read and write to occur synchronously.

Comment: Kaedys, thanks. This help. So there is a no chance of reading a single element more than once. How about one go routine is trying to read a block from the buffer, say it tries to read 100 elements at once because it detects the len() of the buffer is 100. While reading the block, can another go routine read some elements in between so the first go routine will have less than 100 it expected to read in its block?

Comment: Yes, only individual reads are atomic.  If you want to read multiple items at once without the possibility of interleaving, you need to either secure the channel with a mutex, or send slices of objects over the channel instead of single objects.

Comment: Note however, that there's very rarely a point to goroutines checking the current buffer length of a channel.  That information can change due to concurrent reads or writes, and you should be looping over `range ch`, not by a iterator integer.  Just read and process the items as they come.  If order is important, send ordered sets instead of single items.

Comment: Oh, and your nested for loop in the OP is probably an error.  A range loop over a channel will continue indefinitely until the channel is both closed and empty of all elements.  With your double for loop, after the channel is closed and emptied, each of those goroutines will stick in an infinite empty for loop, as they keep recreating a range loop, then instantly exiting it since the channel is empty and closed.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your answer and other reading, I think the best way to use "select" to read the channel in a loop or use a mutex. All good now.

Comment: You only need to use `select` if you have more than one channel read, or if you want a default (ie. nothing could be read) condition.  If it's just a single channel read, the select is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, could different go routine grab the same elem in the channel, or while one go routine is reading the buffer, the other go routines already read and processed some of the elements?

Nope...

I believe a misunderstanding is in difference between non-blocking and thread safe concepts.

#### Non blocking (buffered) channels

> Sends to a buffered channel block only when the buffer is full.

Buffered channels <strike>just like it said</strike> have buffers to store some amount of items. It allows reading goroutine to read without await for writing goroutine put an item to a channel on condition something already written to a channel. If a channel unbuffered it can contain just single item therefore it requires to block channel for writing before a written item be withdrawn. **"Blocking/non-blocking" concept doesn't related to "thread safe" concept and non-blocking doesn't mean not thread safe.**

#### Thread safety of Go channels

Go channels are thread safe in all available ways of use. Channel is a reference type so once allocated with `make` channel could be passed by value because it has implicit pointer to a single memory slot. Obviously contained in a channel item never be copied and couldn't be read twice.